# Querying on a pointer Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So here is the result im trying to achieve i have 2 classes one is Parses User class , and the other is called Content. I am querying Content lets say if A matches B i want to get the appropriate username from the User class and the photo. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what are the names of your classes? It will help me to write a code easily.

Comment: what is A and B which you are going to match?

Comment: sender equalTo username which is current user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I get from your description is *sender* is the property of *Content* class and *username* is the *User* class and you are trying to get the Content of a particular user

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Content"];
[query whereKey:@"sender" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *content in objects)
    {
        // getting the user who created the Content
        PFObject *user = [content objectForKey:@"file"];

        PFFile *imageFile = [user objectForKey:@"photo"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) 
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
                imageView.image = image;
            }
         }];
    }
}];
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to get the photo of the user which is a PFFile stored in the User Class. if seneder matches the current user get the appropriate profile picture of that user from the User class. Which im thinking a pointer would do but i didn't know the correct way to implement it.

Comment: Please let me know the property name of User class in which you have saved the photo?

Comment: @SamBing I just added the code in the post to get the image from User class. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: the property name is "photo"

Comment: @SamBing I edit the post let me know if there is any problem. Please accept the answer if it is helpful. Thanks

Comment: This returns only the content but the photo returns nil .Thank you for your response though

Comment: How you are saving the photo in Parse? May be there is some problem while saving the photo.

Comment: Photo is being saved fine since i can query it normally if i query  on the User class. The challenge for me is querying on the Content Class and getting the photo of the correct user from the User class.

Comment: @SamBing what is the name of your pointer in Content class which links the Content class to User class?

Comment: I named it photo and connected it to a photo , which i want to do for each time a new object is created by sender .

Comment: @SamBing I am little bit of confused about your class diagram. You name the relation between Content and User as _photo_. it will be really helpful if you provide me your Parse relationship diagram

Comment: I assigned that name to the pointer. Class Users has the default columns which are username,password, etc and an extra photo column. Content class has the sender the message and the receiver , also a pointer that should point to Photo column of the User class

Comment: @SamBing The pointer is between the source and the destination class with a column name that makes a link between two classes. So let me know what is the name of that column in Content class of type Pointer<Users>

Comment: Its named "file Pointer<_User>" the exact text of the column.

Comment: @SamBing I just edit the post now. First you get the _Content_ then you get the _User_ from the content object using _file_ and then get the _photo_ from user and fetch in background. I hope that now it will work

Comment: Tried it , didn't exactly work but got me some results. Thanks

Comment: @SamBing what is the problem now?

Comment: Its retrieving the Photo for each row that user is there , which one user can have a lot of rows! Now i can retrieve only one object but thats not what i want since i also want to retrieve the other user.

Comment: could you add a version in Swift, as in title?